# How to specify another scope for the exec statement

Tags: python

I am tracing a function called `tracedFn()`:

```
sys.settrace(traceit)
tracedFn()
sys.settrace(None)
```

the `tracedFn`:

```
def tracedFn():
    foo = False
```

In the `traceit` function I would like to use exec statement to execute statements with variables in the tracedFn() like the following:

```
def traceit(frame, event, trace_arg):
    if event == 'line':
        exec 'foo = True'
        print frame.f_locals
        #foo still False

return traceit
```

but when I print frame.f_locals the exec does not change the foo variable?

Answer (score 0):

See the [`exec` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement); you can specify a context by adding `in` after the expression:

```
exec 'foo = True' in frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals
```

Note that you cannot *add* new locals to a function. You can only change existing local variables (those that have been declared in the function at compile time). So, unless `foo` is already defined in the function you are tracing, you cannot *add* `foo` to that function's local variables.

The global variables are not limited in that manner; you can add to the globals namespace at will; just leave off the `, frame.f_locals` part in that case.

Comment: @fulman: define 'does not work'. Have you tried something simpler first, such as `frame.f_locals['foo'] = True`?

Comment: @Martijin Pieters I mean the locals has not been updated by the exec statement.
even when i use 'frame.f_locals['foo'] = True' then printing frame.f_locals the foo variable remains the same!

Comment: @fulman: Then the `settrace()` function doesn't *let* you add to the locals of that function. Look, but don't touch! You can only change existing locals.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters the exec works fine with the current scope. i mean for all traceit function's locals.

Comment: @fulman: Yeah, I know what you meant. But you can only alter existing function locals, not add new ones.